# How to sign on all pages in Docusign with singHereTabs(absolute positioning)

Tags: docusignapi

{
"emailSubject":"DocuSign API - Please Sign This Document...",
"documents":[
{
"documentId":"1",
"name":"1637231856_1515931438.pdf"
}
],
"recipients":{
"signers":[{"email":"abc@def.com","name":"Admin_User","recipientId":"1","routingOrder":"1","tabs":{"signHereTabs":[{"xPosition":437,"yPosition":3,"documentId":"1","pageNumber":"All Page"}]}}]
},
"eventNotification": {
"url": "myurl",
"loggingEnabled":  "true",
"includeCertificateOfCompletion": "false",
"includeDocuments": "false",
"includeDocumentFields": "true",
"requireAcknowledgment": "true",
"envelopeEvents": [{
"envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
}],
"recipientEvents": [{
"recipientEventStatusCode": "completed"
}]
},
"status":"sent"
}

Answer (score 1):

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-adding-initials-each-page-each-document-your-envelope

This adds an initial to each page of each document in your envelope.
The code in there using SDKs. Not sure if that's ok for you, but that makes it easy to loop.
Say you want to use C#, here is how to modify it from InitialHere tab to SignHere tab:

// You need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication flow var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

```
EnvelopesApi.GetEnvelopeOptions options = new EnvelopesApi.GetEnvelopeOptions { include = "documents,recipients" };
Envelope env = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(accountId, envelopeId, options);
foreach (Signer signer in env.Recipients.Signers)
{
  signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
  signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
  foreach (EnvelopeDocument doc in env.EnvelopeDocuments)
  {
    foreach (Page page in doc.Pages)
    {
      int width = int.Parse(page.Width);
      int height = int.Parse(page.Height);
      var initial = new InitialHere();
      // 100 pixels higher and to the left from the top bottom corner
      sign.XPosition = (width - 100).ToString();
      sign.YPosition = (height - 100).ToString();
      sign.PageNumber = page.Sequence;
      sign.DocumentId = doc.DocumentId;
      sign.RecipientId = signer.RecipientId;
      signer.Tabs.InitialHereTabs.Add(initial);
    }
  }
  envelopesApi.CreateTabs(accountId, env.EnvelopeId, signer.RecipientId, signer.Tabs);
}
```